# Keep only the first column with given name with bind_cols()

Tags: r, dplyr

When using bind_cols function and if tibbles contain columns with the same name, new names are assigned to all of these columns with duplicate names, e.g.

```
> bind_cols(iris, iris)
New names:
* Sepal.Length -> Sepal.Length...1
* Sepal.Width -> Sepal.Width...2
* Petal.Length -> Petal.Length...3
* Petal.Width -> Petal.Width...4
* Species -> Species...5
* ...
```

In this naive example all columns in the iris data frame are duplicated and renamed.

What I want to achieve is that only the first column encountered is kept, while the subsequent column(s) with that name are discarded, and no new names are assigned.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the expected output? all columns from 1st dataframe and 1st column from the second dataframe?

Comment: Why do you not use a `dplyr::full_join()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is an option within `bind_cols()`, but it's trivial to do this in other ways e.g:

```
bind_cols(df1, df2[,!names(df2) %in% names(df1)])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    16
2     2     7    17
3     3     8    18
4     4     9    19
5     5    10    20
```

Data:

```
df1 <- tibble(a = 1:5,
              b = 6:10)
df2 <- tibble(a = 11:15,
              c = 16:20)
```

I used my own data, because it makes it easier to see that the first df's data was used.

Another way:

```
bind_cols(df1, df2, .name_repair = "minimal") %>% select(all_of(unique(names(.))))
```